# Mysql Workbench 6.3 não altera o tipo de dado do atributo na tabela, volta sempre ao anterior

Tags: sql, mysql

Alguém usa a ferramenta de Designer Mysql Workbench na versão 6.3 ?
Estou a ter dificuldade em alterar um tipo de dado de um determinado atributo, sempre que mudo e faço enter ele volta ao atributo anterior... Alguém tem o mesmo problema? Acho que vou voltar nas versões anteriores.

Comment: Não ficou claro em qual local está a tentar. É na área de modelagem gráfica ou na edição de tabela no schema já criado? Eu uso a versão 6.3 e não tenho problemas.

Comment: Suspendi a pergunta porque faltam detalhes para se determinar a causa do erro e o autor não respondeu aos pedidos de esclarecimentos.